# Use AWS CodePipeline variables in a custom stage

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

There's the following buildspec that runs some commands and exports a variable in the end:

```
env:
  exported-variables:
    - PROPERTY_FROM_BUILD
```

I'd like to use this variable inside a custom pipeline stage, but I have no idea how to get it here:

```
import { Stage, StageProps } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
class MyStage extends Stage {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: StageProps) {
    new Stack(this, 'MyStack', {
        PROPERTY_FROM_BUILD: '???'
    });
  }
}
```

Let me post more details just in case. My code pipeline looks like this:

```
const codePipeline = new cdk.pipelines.CodePipeline(this, 'MyPipeline', {...});
codePipeline.addStage(new MyStage(this, 'MyStage', {...})
codePipeline.buildPipeline();
```

As you can see, I just create a pipeline, add my stage and build it. After that is done, I make a codebuild project and action to run my buildspec:

```
const project = new cdk.aws_codebuild.PipelineProject(this, 'MyProject', {
  buildSpec: cdk.aws_codebuild.BuildSpec.fromSourceFilename(`buildspec.yml`),
});
const action = new cdk.aws_codepipeline_actions.CodeBuildAction({
  actionName: 'MyAction',
  project: project,
});
codePipeline.pipeline.addStage({
  stageName: 'MyActionStage',
  actions: [action],
  placement: {
    rightBefore: codePipeline.pipeline.stage('MyStage')
  }
});
```

It works and generates a nice pipeline. Is there any way I can pass my `PROPERTY_FROM_BUILD`  from variable and use it in my stack?

Comment: Not very elegant solution but one way I think of is to store your `PROPERTY_FROM_BUILD`  variable in parameter store using aws cli in your buildspec file. Later on, you can call parameter store to fetch the latest value of this parameter in your stack, like so;

`const latestPropertyFromBuild = ssm.StringParameter.valueForStringParameter(
    this, 'PROPERTY_FROM_BUILD'); `

Comment: have you tried use `process.env.ENV_KEY` e.g. `process.env.PROPERTY_FROM_BUILD`. since you are using typescript, dont forget to add `@types/node` in the dev dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it took me about a week to figure this out, I've managed to make it work after all. Let me leave the solution here, in case someone else encounters the issue:

Before even starting, extend your `CodeBuildAction` with a custom namespace, like:

```
const action = new cdk.aws_codepipeline_actions.CodeBuildAction({
  actionName: 'MyAction',
  project: project,
  variablesNamespace: 'my_action_namespace',
});
```

First of all, you've got to figure out the index of your deployment stage, like:

```
const deployIdx = codePipeline.pipeline.stages.indexOf(codePipeline.pipeline.stage('Deploy'));
```

Then, find all actions of type "changeset replace":

```
const actionsIdxs = codePipeline.pipeline.stage('Deploy').actions.filter(x => x.actionProperties.category === 'Deploy').map((x,i)=>i);
```

Next, use this [Escape Hatches](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html) feature to edit the generated template and attach [the pipeline variable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/reference-variables.html) as `ParameterOverrides` to all deployment actions:

```
const cfnPipeline = codePipeline.pipeline.node.findChild('Resource') as cdk.aws_codepipeline.CfnPipeline;
for(const i of actionsIdxs){
  cfnPipeline.addOverride(
    `Properties.Stages.${deployIdx}.Actions.${i}.Configuration.ParameterOverrides`,
    JSON.stringify({
        // Use lowercase-only here to match the autogenerated name of the CfnParameter.
        propertyfrombuild: "#{my_action_namespace.PROPERTY_FROM_BUILD}"
    }));
}
```

And then, finally, in my stack, I can access the value like this:

```
const PROPERTY_FROM_BUILD = new cdk.CfnParameter(this, 'propertyfrombuild').valueAsString;
```

Make sure you name the variable all-lowercase with no special characters, and place it in your stack (not in a child construct).

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this is not a complete answer, but the main points I did to get this working.

Buildspec:

```yaml
env:
  exported-variables:
    # Make the JAR filename available to the CodePipeline
    - JAR_OUTPUT_NAME
phases:
  build:
    commands:
      # Set the output variable
      - JAR_OUTPUT_NAME=App-${CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION:0:7}.jar
      # Your build steps would go here...
```

The build action in pipeline:

```
const buildAction = new codepipelineActions.CodeBuildAction({
    actionName: 'Build',
    project: codeBuildProject,
    input: sourceOutput,
    outputs: [codeBuildOutput],
    variablesNamespace: 'BuildVariables',
});
```

Action that uses the output variable:

```
const prepareAction = new codepipelineActions.CloudFormationCreateReplaceChangeSetAction({
    actionName: 'App.Prepare',
    stackName: 'App',
    changeSetName: 'codepipeline-#{codepipeline.PipelineExecutionId}',
    templatePath: codeBuildOutput.atPath('stack.yml'),
    templateConfiguration: codeBuildOutput.atPath(
        `app-parameters.json`
    ),
    parameterOverrides: {
        // Here we use the output variable from CodeBuild
        CodeContentFileKey: `app/code/${buildAction.variable('JAR_OUTPUT_NAME')}`,
    },
    cfnCapabilities: [cdk.CfnCapabilities.ANONYMOUS_IAM],
    adminPermissions: true,
    account: deployEnv.account,
    region: deployEnv.region,
    role: cdkDeploymentRoles[deployEnv.environment],
    deploymentRole: cdkCloudformationExecRoles[deployEnv.environment],
    runOrder: 1,
});
```